# Android - WebView inside ScrollView leave white space at the bottom

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview

I want to add multiple WebViews in a scroll container. In order to do this I am adding them programatically inside LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/scrollView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

 </ScrollView>
```

Now the problem is when I am loading the data in WebViews using loadDataWithBaseURL() method, WebViews are leaving some extra space at the bottom. Not able to find a proper solution for this problem. Can anybody please tell me why it is happening?

Comment: not need to put webview under a scroll view. Just have a button and on click load a webview with url. Have a activity with one webview. pass the url to the actiivity on appropriate button click and load the url in the same webview. User would not like make a long scroll to view the data.

Comment: I have such requirement for my project. Everything is working like a charm except the above problem.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: maybe this doesnt help but i have been having the same problem with the white space, in my case if i remove the ScrollView the webview does not scrolls properly, there is no white space tho but the app does not scroll property. I am trying to find the solution here too. Hang in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank",
                Utils.getHtmlData(article.getContent()), "text/html",
                "utf-8", null);
        rl_wrapper.removeAllViews();
        rl_wrapper.addView(webView);
```

i use a wrapper take the place of the webview, english is not my native language,but also hope it can help you.